# Undefined symbols when using opt with custom LLVM pass on Mac

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, linker, llvm

I would like some help figuring out this head-scratcher. Sorry for the long post!

### Environment

- Mac OS X, 10.10.5 "Yosemite"
- Clang/LLVM 6.0.0, built from source on 2018 Mar 9
- C++14 source code
- CMake 3.11.0
- Ninja 1.8.2

Note: I do NOT have Apple's Clang/LLVM toolchain -- I carefully removed it in 2016 before replacing it with the UIUC stable build available online. Every issue I could find related to this online was because of something Apple-specific. I double-checked to make sure that the Clang/LLVM toolchain I linked in CMake is indeed the right one (the only one I have).

Please let me know if you need to know anything else.

### Background

So I'm writing a custom LLVM pass with my own C++ header/class files. I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── lib
│   ├── libgraphs.a
│   ├── libprograms.a
│   ├── libvisitors.a
│   └── passes.so
├── include
│   ├── graphs
│   │   └── (...)
│   ├── passes
│   │   └── (...)
│   ├── programs
│   │   └── (...)
│   └── visitors
│       └── (...)
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── graphs
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── (...)
    ├── passes
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── (...)
    ├── programs
    │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
    │   └── (...)
    └── visitors
        ├── CMakeLists.txt
        └── (...)
```

The `(...)` markings contain custom header files in `include` and C++ implementations in `src`. I'm somewhat sure that this setup is correct, and everything compiles fine.

I'm using CMake to string together the whole project, and one thing I'm having an issue with right now is link-time errors. Right now, each `CMakeLists.txt` is nicely structured in a per-subdirectory level. However, I'm not sure if things are actually getting linked together. So all of my library files get generated to `lib`. Here I have the shared library of the actual pass as well as the static libraries generated for each subdirectory. I don't do anything special right now to link these together, and I think that's the issue.

### Problem

What I'm trying to do is the following. I have a very simple `Hello.cpp` file in `programs`, and I have already compiled that to bitcode using

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -emit-llvm -c src/programs/Hello.cpp -o src/programs/Hello.bc
```

Then, I want to apply my pass (flag anonymized below):

```
opt -load lib/passes.so -[FLAG] < src/programs/Hello.bc
```

When I do this, I get the following link-time error (mangled name anonymized below):

```
Error opening 'lib/passes.so': dlopen(lib/passes.so, 9):
  Symbol not found: [mangled_name]
    Referenced from: lib/passes.so
    Expected in: flat namespace
  in lib/passes.so
```

### Attempt towards solution

I used `c++filt` on the mangled name to see what it was, and it was a class name from one of my custom header files:

```
$ c++filt [mangled_name]
  vtable for [namespace]::[custom_visitor_class]
```

So it seems to me that the static library `libvisitors.a` is at the least not getting linked into the shared library `passes.so`, so there is a link-time failure despite all units compiling fine.

Is there a way to resolve this? In the `CMakeLists.txt`, I tried using `link_directories(lib)` so that the static libraries would all be linked in, but I get the same result every time. I've spent a few hours on Google and various older StackOverflow posts, but everything is either (1) from an older version of LLVM with different configurations or (2) a solution that didn't seem to work for me (although it's possible that I misinterpreted it!).

I really need some help with getting rid of these link-time errors. I think they only occur when I use custom headers, as when I just use the standard LLVM libraries (which are currently linked in fine) without any of my own wrappers, any generated `.so` works fine and does what it is supposed to.

The one thing that I have managed to determine from Google is that this is OS X-specific and likely wouldn't occur on Linux. Unfortunately I don't have a spare Linux machine with a LLVM toolchain setup on-hand, but I'm getting really convinced to spend 2 hours to build the latest release from source and test my program on that environment.

Any ideas?